# How to tell if a Bokeh document is no longer visible

Tags: bokeh

For my bokeh server application I run a periodic callback on a document object.  Unfortunately that periodic callback has a circular reference back to the document, which seems to keep everything alive.

One way to avoid this situation would be to check to see if the Document object is still in use (someone is still looking at the document through a web browser) and then removing my circular reference explicitly.  Is this information of whether or not a document is still alive available somewhere?  A quick look through the docs and API didn't show anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is `curdoc().session_context.session.destroyed` however it's unclear what your actual situation is. The code below never prints `True` because the callback stops running when the session is destroyed. Your question would benefit from an MRE.

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc

def cb():
    print(curdoc().session_context.session.destroyed)

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(cb, 200)
```